# When I double click on a cell to open a form, a checkbox on the form behind my cursor is checked/unchecked. How can I prevent this from happening?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form that appears on a double click event of a specific cell.

The form contains a list box with a bunch of checkboxes in it and in my _Activate() sub, the checkboxes are set to true or false based on values on the active sheet.

The trouble is that when the form opens up behind the cursor, the second click of the double click that opens the form is also checking/unchecking a checkbox in the form.

I've tried sticking "DoEvents" in the activate sub before the code sets the checkbox values but it hasn't made a difference - The checkbox behind my cursor where the form opens will be checked/unchecked.

I don't expect that the code will help much but it is essentially as below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Target = Range("aParticularRangeName") Then
        frmSelectStuff.Show
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim iRegions As Integer
    Dim sRecheck As Variant
    Dim sRecheckList() As String

    sRecheckList = Split(ActiveCell.Value, "; ")
    For Each sRecheck In sRecheckList
        For iRegions = 0 To lbRegionsTemp.ListCount - 1
            If sRecheck = lbRegionsTemp.List(iRegions) Then lbRegionsTemp.Selected(iRegions) = True
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be very helpful, if you showed us your code. ;)

Comment: @Tom Done.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Ah, there we have it. The problem lies within the `BeforeDoubleClick`-event. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098369/avoid-selection-in-a-form-when-double-click

Comment: @Tom Awesome!  I looked for that but couldn't find it to save my life.  Duplicate question then.  The shame!  +1

Answer (score 0):

What about using Cancel = True?

```
If Target = Range("aParticularRangeName") Then
    Cancel = True
    frmSelectStuff.Show
End If
```